# Sum of the two dimentional array in Java

Tags: java

This is a homework question and im still a newbie to java.
Write a code segment that computes the sum of all the values in marks.

This is my answer and it has compilation errors. Please help

```
class myArray{

    public static void main(String args []){

        int [] [] marks = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9}, {10,11,12}};
        for(int i = 0; i<marks.length; i++){
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j <marks[i].length; j++) {
                sum = sum + makrs[j][i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Comment: See the compilation errors and try to debug your code , it helps to learn.

Comment: What happens if you simply compile it, which line does the error point you to? It's a simple mistake actually, so you really should check the compiler output like @shg said.

Comment: int[][] and String[] args is more traditional, but I don't remember off the top of my head if that would give errors. And you wrote makrs someplace.

Comment: You're very close to solution :) BTW this is something compiler won't say you: In Java there is a convention to start the name of the class with a capital letter (class MyArray instead of class myArray).

Comment: Also add the compiler output to your post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two syntactical errors and one type.

1. Move `int sum =0;` above `for` loop as you need it outside the loop to print the value
2. Correct marks reading index from `marks[j][i]` to `marks[i][j]`
3. Correct the typo in the same line as above (`sum = sum + makrs[j][i];)`. You have typed `makrs` in place of `marks`

   ```
   int [] [] marks = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9}, {10,11,12}};         

   int sum = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<marks.length; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j <marks[i].length; j++){
           sum = sum + marks[i][j];
       }
   }
   System.out.println(sum);
   ```

Comment: thank you very much brother :D i have whole lot of assignments to do. Will you be able to help me on those also ?

Also can you please explain the mechanism here ?

My programs works fine now :D thanks to you

 int [] [] marks = {{1,2,3,4,5}, {6,7,8,9}, {10,11,12}};

  int sum = 0;
  
  for(int i = 0; i<marks.length; i++){
   
   for(int j = 0; j <marks[i].length; j++){
    sum = sum + marks[i][j];
    }
   }
  System.out.println(sum);
 }

Comment: Let's understand it this way. Your two dimensional array represents a table with 3 rows and 5 columns. First `for` loop is iterating your rows (3 times), and second `for` loop is iterating columns (5 times) within each row and one row at a time. Once you locate row+column e.g. first row, first column, you get your value at that position as 1, which you are adding in your sum variable.

Comment: thank you again brother... i have lot more questions to ask and assignments to get done..are you free to help ? regards

Comment: Ohh sorry bro..I just did it..im new to stackoverflow :) Hope its ok now ?